# How to get only the dates near keyword using regex

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
import re
s = """Sentence 1: Admit on TOM, SINI [STOM] Dismissal Date: 07/20/2021
    Sentence 2: Admit 08/07/2021 TOM, SINI [STOM]
    Sentence 3: Adm: 09/07/2018 TOM, SINI [STOM]"""

admission_keys = ['Admit','Adm:']
date_patterns = ['\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{4}','\d{1,2}[-]\d{1,2}[-]\d{2,4}']
pattern = re.findall(r"(?:(?:" + '|'.join(admission_keys)  + ").*?(?:" + '|'.join(date_patterns) + '))',s)
print(pattern)

Required solution: Admit 08/07/2021,Adm: 09/07/2018
```

The solution is taking "Admit on TOM, SINI [STOM] Dismissal Date: 07/20/2021". Is there any solution that gets only near Admit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go:

```py
import re


admission_keys = ['Admit','Adm:']
date_patterns = ['\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{4}', '\d{1,2}[-]\d{1,2}[-]\d{2,4}']

adm_pattern = "|".join(admission_keys)
date_pattern = "|".join(date_patterns)
pattern = re.compile(rf"((?:{adm_pattern}) (?:{date_pattern}))")

s = """
Sentence 1: Admit on TOM, SINI [STOM] Dismissal Date: 07/20/2021
Sentence 2: Admit 08/07/2021 TOM, SINI [STOM]
Sentence 3: Adm: 09/07/2018 TOM, SINI [STOM]
Sentence 4: Adm: 4-12-2014
Sentence 5: Admit 05-25-16
"""

pattern.findall(s)
# ['Admit 08/07/2021', 'Adm: 09/07/2018', 'Adm: 4-12-2014', 'Admit 05-25-16']
```

Comment: Can you give the solution using .join for array of elements.

Comment: Not sure exactly what you mean, but see my edit.

Comment: I have list of patterns for dates in array ['\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{4}','\d{1,2}[-]\d{1,2}[-]\d{2,4}'] as well as admission_keys = ['Admit','Adm:']. I need to use .join(admission_keys) and .join(date_patterns) to find solution

Comment: I cannot use or "|" symbol for every patterns

Comment: How to put .join(admission_keys) and .join(date_patterns) inside re.compile(r"((?:Admit|Adm:) \d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{4})")

Comment: @Arunkumar see my edit. I think I understand what you're asking now.